# Scheme: change value of an element in a list

Tags: list, lisp, scheme

I hate using SO as a way to find simple functions, but I really can't find a function like this anywhere:

Given a list (1 2 3 4 5), I'd like the equivalent of (PHP's, Perl's, Python's)

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);   
$a[3] = 100;
```

Which results in (1 2 3 100 5)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered that if this is the kind of functionality that you want out of data structure, random re-assignment of cells, then perhaps you don't really want a list, but instead, maybe a vector?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write `list-set!` of Guile, like so:

```
(define a (list 1 2 3 4))     ; a is '(1 2 3 4)

(define (list-set! list k val)
    (if (zero? k)
        (set-car! list val)
        (list-set! (cdr list) (- k 1) val)))

(list-set! a 2 100)           ; a is '(1 2 100 4)
```

(Tried this in DrRacket.)

Comment: I was using `list-set!` in `guile`.  This let me port the script to `chicken`.

Answer (score 5):

Using standard functions without any SRFI:

```
(set-car! (list-tail lst k) val)
```

Answer (score 5):

I may be a bit late, but I have a different answer.

Part of the functional-program paradigm seems to be to try to avoid modifying data when possible. For efficiency reasons you may want to go with the other answers here. But otherwise, consider a non-mutating function such as this:

```
(define (list-with lst idx val)
  (if (null? lst)
    lst
    (cons
      (if (zero? idx)
        val
        (car lst))
      (list-with (cdr lst) (- idx 1) val))))
```

Which passes the following tests:

```
(describe "a function that returns a list with a 'changed' value"
  (it "can modify the edges of lists without having 1-off errors"
    (expect (list-with '(1 2 3 4 5) 0 99) (be equal? '(99 2 3 4 5)))
    (expect (list-with '(1 2 3 4 5) 4 99) (be equal? '(1 2 3 4 99))))
  (it "has something to do with creating new lists"
    (expect (list-with '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 99) (be equal? '(1 2 99 4 5))))
  (it "doesnt just modify the contents of the original list"
    (let ((a '(1 2 3 4 5)))
      (list-with a 2 99)
      (expect a (be equal? '(1 2 3 4 5))))))
```

(The code is written in Chicken Scheme and the tests with the "missbehave" library. But it seems like pretty portable Scheme.)

Answer (score 3):

Guile has a built-in function called `list-set!` that does exactly what you want, using zero-based indices.  For your example, you would have:

```
(define a '(1 2 3 4 5))
(list-set! a 3 100)
```

I don't think this is standard Scheme, however, and I don't know if it's really efficient.  For a fixed-length array you should probably use a vector:

```
(define a2 #(1 2 3 4 5))
(vector-set! a2 3 100)
```

I'm pretty sure this is part of the language standard.

Comment: Normally, `set!` in Scheme doesn't support places. But with SRFI 17 loaded (if your implementation supports it---Guile does), you can use `(set! (list-ref lst 3) 100)` if you want. EDIT: Oops, that doesn't work in Guile, but `(set! (caddr lst) 100)` does.

Comment: I think the Scheme equivalent of nth is list-ref, which unfortunately returns a value not a reference (at least in my environment)

Comment: Note thaht "returns a reference" is something that doesn't exist in either Scheme or Lisp.  The way that CL's `setf` works is at the macro level, it doesn't work on some "returned reference".  Same goes for srfi-17 in Scheme: it doesn't use a "returned reference", instead, it uses the `set!`-ed function to find a setter function.

Comment: @amindfv Yeah, I found `list-ref` but didn't include it in my edit because of exactly what you said.

Comment: @Eli You be careful, mister, or I'll take away the upvote for your answer to my only question ever on SO.  Seriously, you can tell that I don't get to do much Lisp any more...thank you for correcting me.  Heck, I'm lucky to get to do any reading or programming these days...

Comment: :)  No problems...  I'm just pointing it out because my experience with these things is that many people *do* expect there to be some kind of a reference value, then they get surprised when they realize there isn't, and often, that continues with suggestions on how to implement such values after all...